# Laravel redirect to wrong url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, laravel

My project has Wordpress and Laravel
Wordpress Url
http://localhost/aaa
Laravel Project Url
http://localhost/aaa/bbb

When I access to Laravel by http://localhost/aaa/bbb/ works fine.
But without / in the end like http://localhost/aaa/bbb It redirects me to
http://localhost/bbb

This is htaccess in Wordpress file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?bbb/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?bbb/?$
RewriteRule . /bbb/public/index.php [L]
```

This is htaccess in Laravel Project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say...

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^aaa/(.*)/$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You may try this in laravel htaccess